# Как улучшить перформанс приложения на react native?

Tags: reactjs, redux, mobile, native

Задание улучшить перформанс приложения написанного на React Native.
Подскажите в какую сторону двигаться?
Каким образом отследить перформанс до изменений.
Каким образом можно улучшить его?

Comment: в браузерном реакте достаточно поставить плагин, в нем выбрать крыжик 'Highlight updates' и ловить лишние перерисовки. в мобильной разработке посмотрел, народ предлагает запускать приложение на слабом устройстве и замерять fps )) я же предлагаю подойти к задаче теоритически: обернуть все что только можно хуками useMemo и useCallback, а все компоненты, зависящие только от своих свойств в React.memo. подробнее [тут](https://habr.com/ru/articles/706730/)